# How can I add a static public folder to my node server?

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have created a new OpenShift node application with their wizard and it has created an index file in the root of the app. I would like to put everything within a public folder and then set this folder as the static.

I'm very new to Node and cannot find a solution to this that doesn't break my OpenShift server when I commit my code. I assume this is pretty straightforward thing to do in node.

UPDATE:

Node uses Express so I have read that I can use this code to set a static folder :

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

But adding this breaks my server (yet again). I get the 503 when running it on OpenShift.

Here's my server.js code :

```
#!/bin/env node
//  OpenShift sample Node application
var fs      = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');


/**
 *  Define the sample application.
 */
var SampleApp = function() {

//  Scope.
var self = this;

/*  ================================================================  */
/*  Helper functions.                                                 */
/*  ================================================================  */

/**
 *  Set up server IP address and port # using env variables/defaults.
 */
self.setupVariables = function() {
    //  Set the environment variables we need.
    self.ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
    self.port      = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;

    if (typeof self.ipaddress === "undefined") {
        //  Log errors on OpenShift but continue w/ 127.0.0.1 - this
        //  allows us to run/test the app locally.
        console.warn('No OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP var, using 127.0.0.1');
        self.ipaddress = "127.0.0.1";
    };
};


/**
 *  Populate the cache.
 */
self.populateCache = function() {
    if (typeof self.zcache === "undefined") {
        self.zcache = { 'index.html': '' };
    }

    //  Local cache for static content.
    self.zcache['index.html'] = fs.readFileSync('./index.html');
};


/**
 *  Retrieve entry (content) from cache.
 *  @param {string} key  Key identifying content to retrieve from cache.
 */
self.cache_get = function(key) { return self.zcache[key]; };


/**
 *  terminator === the termination handler
 *  Terminate server on receipt of the specified signal.
 *  @param {string} sig  Signal to terminate on.
 */
self.terminator = function(sig){
    if (typeof sig === "string") {
       console.log('%s: Received %s - terminating sample app ...',
                   Date(Date.now()), sig);
       process.exit(1);
    }
    console.log('%s: Node server stopped.', Date(Date.now()) );
};


/**
 *  Setup termination handlers (for exit and a list of signals).
 */
self.setupTerminationHandlers = function(){
    //  Process on exit and signals.
    process.on('exit', function() { self.terminator(); });

    // Removed 'SIGPIPE' from the list - bugz 852598.
    ['SIGHUP', 'SIGINT', 'SIGQUIT', 'SIGILL', 'SIGTRAP', 'SIGABRT',
     'SIGBUS', 'SIGFPE', 'SIGUSR1', 'SIGSEGV', 'SIGUSR2', 'SIGTERM'
    ].forEach(function(element, index, array) {
        process.on(element, function() { self.terminator(element); });
    });
};


/*  ================================================================  */
/*  App server functions (main app logic here).                       */
/*  ================================================================  */

/**
 *  Create the routing table entries + handlers for the application.
 */
self.createRoutes = function() {
    self.routes = { };

    self.routes['/asciimo'] = function(req, res) {
        var link = "http://i.imgur.com/kmbjB.png";
        res.send("<html><body><img src='" + link + "'></body></html>");
    };

    self.routes['/'] = function(req, res) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.send(self.cache_get('index.html') );
    };
};


/**
 *  Initialize the server (express) and create the routes and register
 *  the handlers.
 */
self.initializeServer = function() {

    self.createRoutes();
    self.app = express.createServer();

    // view engine setup
    self.app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    self.app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
    //app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
    self.app.use(logger('dev'));
    self.app.use(bodyParser.json());
    self.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    self.app.use(cookieParser());
    self.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    self.app.use('/', routes);
    self.app.use('/users', users);

    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    self.app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      var err = new Error('Not Found');
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    });

    // error handlers

    // development error handler
    // will print stacktrace
    if (self.app.get('env') === 'development') {
      self.app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
          message: err.message,
          error: err
        });
      });
    }

    // production error handler
    // no stacktraces leaked to user
    self.app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
      });
    });

    module.exports = app;

    //  Add handlers for the app (from the routes).
    for (var r in self.routes) {
        self.app.get(r, self.routes[r]);
    }
};


/**
 *  Initializes the sample application.
 */
self.initialize = function() {
    self.setupVariables();
    self.populateCache();
    self.setupTerminationHandlers();

    // Create the express server and routes.
    self.initializeServer();
};


/**
 *  Start the server (starts up the sample application).
 */
self.start = function() {
    //  Start the app on the specific interface (and port).
    self.app.listen(self.port, self.ipaddress, function() {
        console.log('%s: Node server started on %s:%d ...',
                    Date(Date.now() ), self.ipaddress, self.port);
    });
};

};   /*  Sample Application.  */



/**
 *  main():  Main code.
 */
var zapp = new SampleApp();
zapp.initialize();
zapp.start();
```

Comment: There is no built in function in Node to serve static files. Your either code it yourself which wouldn't be hard, either use libraries (e.g [node-static](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static))

Comment: OpenShift uses Express so I think I can use this : app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Comment: I thought OpenShift is just a cloud hosting

Comment: It is yes. I can create an Express web app in node but when I try and port the code over to work on my OpenShift instance I just get a 503 error. I'm not a Node developer so am struggling to understand how to do this.

Comment: Any logs from the server?

Comment: Not very helpful:Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory './index.html'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15)
    at self.populateCache

Comment: Do you have `index.html` in the root folder? This line requires it `self.zcache['index.html'] = fs.readFileSync('./index.html');`

Comment: No. But that's the point: I'm trying to move everything into a folder called 'public' and server it all from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77709/discussion-between-zaynetro-and-lee-probert).

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I'd answer this for someone else who doesn't understand Node:

I got it to work using the standard boilerplate code that OpenShift give you when you create a new node app. To move everything into a public folder and serve files from within it you only need to edit the code below in server.js :

```
self.populateCache = function() {
    if (typeof self.zcache === "undefined") {
        self.zcache = { 'index.html': '' };
    }

    //  Local cache for static content.
    self.zcache['index.html'] = fs.readFileSync('./public/index.html'); // < ---- THIS WAS EDITED TO INCLUDE /public
};
```

and then this a bit later :

```
self.initializeServer = function() {
    self.createRoutes();
    self.app = express.createServer();
    self.app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // < ---- THIS WAS ADDED

    //  Add handlers for the app (from the routes).
    for (var r in self.routes) {
        self.app.get(r, self.routes[r]);
    }
};
```

Hope this helps someone later.

:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Exprees and Path modulesto include static files like:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: Do I need to add path as a dependency in the package.json file?

Comment: Logs suggest it is still trying to find my index file in the root : ENOENT, no such file or directory './index.html'. It's now in 'public'.

Comment: @HarishMohanani, you do **NOT** need `path` dependency in `package.json`. Path is build in module in Node.js

Comment: latest error is "Cannot find module './routes/index'"

Comment: do you have routes directory in your project?

Comment: @zaynetro yes path is built-in module in node.js. Sorry my bad